# How to use the Mailto function in PHP

Tags: php, forms, mailto

I am really new at all of this and need help... I have a forum I am trying to send, but for some reason it is not sending. The mailto function is not sending an email on the server, and it is also not refreshing to redirect.html. Here is my code:

```
 <?php 
                $problem = FALSE;
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
                        $problem = TRUE;
                        print '<p class="important">&bull;&nbsp;What is your name?</p>';
                    }   
                    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
                        $problem =TRUE;
                        print '<p class="important">&bull;&nbsp;What is your email?</p>';
                    }
                    if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
                        $problem =TRUE;
                        print '<p class="important">&bull;&nbsp;What is your message?</p>';
                    }
                    if ($problem = TRUE) {print '<br />';}
                    }
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" id="contact_me" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="160">Your Name:<span class="important">*</span></td>
                    <td width="340"><input name="name" type="text" size="30" value="<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { if (isset($_POST['name'])) { print htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); }}?>"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><p>Your Email:<span class="important">*</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td><input name="email" type="text" size="30" placeholder="example@example.com" value="<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { if (isset($_POST['email'])) { print htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); }}?>"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Message:<span class="important">*</span></td>
                    <td><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Your message here"><?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){if(isset($_POST['message'])){print htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);}}?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
            </table><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
            </form>
            <?php
            // Start the email function
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    if ($problem == FALSE) { // holy cow they didn't mess up
                        $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
                        $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
                        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];   

                        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
                        $subject="Mathew Blair - Contact form"; 
                        mail("mathewblair@live.com", $subject, $message, $from);

                        Header("Location: redirect.html");
                    }
            }
            ?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your last condition

```
 if ($problem = TRUE) {print '<br />';}
```

you are not checking if `problem` is `true` but you are SETTING `problem` to `TRUE`

change it to:

```
 if ($problem == TRUE) {print '<br />';}
```

Comment: Thank you! now I am getting a header error. Here it is: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:135) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 184

Comment: 1) remove whitespace before `<?php`
2) if that doesn't work check if you're not `echo`ing anything before e.g. session_start() or header()

Comment: This is all one page, I am not using a header().. There is also no sessions being used. I can always just use a META refresh to

Comment: ah! add `ob_start();` at the beggining of the code. You're using header at redirect

Comment: What does that do? and that didn't fix it..

Comment: it buffers your output (`echo`) so the headers can be added later to the start of the response

Comment: make sure you have removed whitespace and/or BOM char before your `<?php`

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work using the html meta refresh tag... Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

The server that you are on will need to have a mail service such as sendmail or postfix installed.

On Ubuntu, that's

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

You may have to change your mail configuration in your php.ini (http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

Also, for sending email, I found that it was better to use a full class instead of just the mail function. Such a class will make it easier to connect with a 3rd party mail gateway, such as gmail. So, you'll be able to send email from your web application via gmail's SMTP servers, which is much better for not having your sent emails detected as spam. Here are three good packages for that. I recommend swiftmailer.

http://swiftmailer.org/

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a SMTP configured in order for the `mail` to work.

The `mail` function could also be malfunctioning because of a configuration error. You will have to edit your php.ini file.